# Get table data in JSON from Oracle DB and load to SQL server DB using Python (3.7)

Tags: python, sql, json, sql-server, oracle

New to Python and JSON, I am trying to do the following in Python 3.7:

1.Connect to Oracle database

2.Get data from specific table in proper JSON output

3.Connect to SQL server

4.Load data from step 2. in corresponding table in SQL Server (table is already created there)

I am not sure how to get table name in JSON output in step 2 and how to further load it in SQL server using Python.
I am getting this kind of JSON output at the moment, without a table name:

```
[
 {
  "col1": 128583,
  "col2": "surname",
  "col3": "93 3j-039"
 }
]
```

And here is the code so far:

```or-tag-here
import cx_Oracle
import pyodbc
import json
import MySQLdb


#Connect to Oracle DB and get table data output as JSON object
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='xxx', password='xxx', dsn=dsn_tns)
c = conn.cursor()

#Allows to pass date objects
class DatetimeEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj): # pylint: disable=method-hidden
        try:
            return super(DatetimeEncoder, obj).default(obj)
        except TypeError:
            return str(obj)

cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from test_table' )

r = [dict((cursor.description[i][0], value) \
               for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
print(json.dumps(r,cls=DatetimeEncoder, indent=2))  #How to return name of table as well?

#SQL Server import data
#Connect to SQL Server
server = 'xxx'
database = 'xxx'
username = 'xxx'
password = 'xx'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

# not a working code at the moment, just a rough idea
def insertDb():
    try:
        cursor.execute("""
        INSERT INTO nameoftable(nameofcolumn) \
        VALUES (%s) """, (row))
        cursor.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print (e)
```

Comment: What is your SQL Server version? And, note, that the JSON in the question has duplicate key (`col2`).

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2018.

Comment: SQL Server 2018 is not a valid SQL Server version, but I assume that you use at least SQL Server 2016. From this version, SQL Server supports JSON, so you need to use an appropriate T-SQL statement to parse the JSON from the question and insert the content of the JSON input into a table.

Comment: If your Oracle query returns a large number of rows, tune [`Cursor.arraysize`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Comment: Oracle DB has a lot of JSON functionality that you may want to review, start with the [cx_Oracle manual](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/json_data_type.html).